# excel adjusting formula based on how many columns

Tags: vba, excel

I have a working macro in place on excel VBA. In one of the cells, I have a formula which has a formula of finding the total for that column. However once I run the macro, it deleted all empty/blank columns and so I needed to figure out a code I could put into the macro that can re-arrange the formula based on how many columns I have?

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()

ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="OperationHUMP"
ActiveSheet.Select

If (Range("C3") = "Change") Then
    MsgBox "Client Cost (excluding VAT) cannot exceed total budget for the campaign. Please check and insert correct prices.", vbOK, "Client Cost too High"
    Exit Sub
    End If

With ActiveSheet.Range("B18:B74")
.Value = .Value
.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete

Dim cel As Range
For Each cel In ActiveSheet.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
cel.Formula = Replace(cel.Formula, "#REF!", "")
Next

 Application.DisplayAlerts = False
End With


Dim SaveName As String
SaveName = ActiveSheet.Range("C5").Text

ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="OperationHUMP"


With ActiveWorkbook

Dim sht As Object

For Each sht In Sheets
If sht.Name <> "Media Plan" Then
sht.Visible = xlSheetHidden
End If
Next sht


     ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="OperationHUMP"
    .Worksheets("Media Plan").CommandButton2.Visible = False
    .Worksheets("Media Plan").CommandButton1.Visible = False

    .SaveAs "S\" & SaveName & ".xls"
End With

Workbooks.Open ("S\" & SaveName & ".xls")
Workbooks("Media Plan Template Most Recent in Access.xlsb").Close False

End Sub
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Syed can you please provide some examples of the code you have so far and a bit more description as to what is going wrong?

Comment: the code is too big to fit into this comment section so it isnt let me put it in. When i put the SUM function over a range of cells in excel, once i click the macro button it gets rid of the blank columns. However this doesn't update the formula and so it returns a #ref error. Does that help to make it more clear?

Comment: A little bit clearer thanks, have you tried setting the the formula of that cell at the end of the macro routine? You should be able to edit your question to include the code I think

Comment: Hi, maxhob, i have just edited my question to include the code. Any suggestions? What do you mean by setting the formula at the end of the macro?

Answer (score 0):

You can try a *repair* to your formulas after the delete operation. Something like this should do

```
Dim cel as Range
For Each cel In Activesheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
    cel.Formula = Replace(cel.Formula, "#REF!", "")
Next
```

You might need to do the replace many times, since you might delete many rows (or columns) and so it may result in many occurrences of `$REF!` in the same formula. If that's necessary tell me.

p.s.: Initially the problem occurs only in formulas that encompass multi-area ranges, i.e. `=SUM(E:G,P:Q,S:S)` and then your code removes completely one of those areas, for example the column `S` or *both* columns P and Q in the example above. When this happens, the area's address is replaced in the formula by `#REF`.  Apart of that, Excel adjusts automatically the formula for those areas that were not completely deleted.

Comment: would this adjust the range over which the SUM function is applied? I still would need the total amount of the new range after the columns are deleted?

Comment: @Syed plz see my *p.s* for additional clarification.

Comment: Also, i just tried to add this in but if gives me an error and highlights the for each cel line

Comment: what is p.s? I am new to stack so I'm not aware of this?

Comment: I mean the "remark," I added at the end of my answer. Well the error is because `cel` was not declared. I added that. The code should be placed right after your delete operation (   `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete`   )

Comment: i just done what you said above but i still get an error. The same line is highlightes as yellow?

Comment: did you add the line `Dim cel as Range` ?

Comment: Ok, now please copy/paste my code and put it at the right place then then edit your question to show that part of the code, and the error message

Comment: `Activesheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
`, sorry  @Syed

Comment: hi ash, now the 'cel.Formula = Replace(cel.Formula, "#REF!", "")' part is giving an error and highlights in yellow!

Comment: @ A.S.H the error message says run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error and once i debug it it highlights that line in yellow

Comment: :O Must be due to other types of formulas. Maybe some types of formulas (other than `Sum`) may raise an error. Try to put some `on error resume next` before that line and see which formulas  stay unrepaired.